# Accurev delete a file that has been kept/promoted or scrub contents from all versions

Tags: accurev

We have the need to remove a file from Accurev existence.  We have defuncted the file, but versions of the file can still be viewed which enables a user to re-create the code found in the file.

Is there a way to delete a file from the Accurev database, or at least remove the contents from being visible from all versions of a specific file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the command 'accurev archive'.

This will remove the data containers which will prevent someone from viewing the file.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I found the reference to the command using your post here: http://www.accurev.com/download/docs/4.7.4b_books/AccuRev_4_7_Admin.pdf  From there we used the accurev archive command, followed by the accurev reclaim command.  This completely removes the file from anybody retrieving the contents as well as unarchiving the file.